# Windows Phone Page navigation in MVVM

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I am using MVVM in one of the app. I have created different project for Model, View and View Model. 
I need to navigate to another XAML from ViewModel. I found some solution using MVVM light. Is there any way of implementing navigation from view model without using MVVM light.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as that,

IF you want to navigate from page1 to page2,

```
private void MoveToPage2FromPage1()
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

[`How to perform page navigation on Windows Phone 8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626521%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can store current page url on a notify property of Shared ViewModel in App. After that, it is easy to catch the change of this url and navigate to the correct url by observing it.

```
public class AppViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string CurrentPageURL { get; set; }

    private string _currentPageURL;
    public string CurrentPageURL
    {
        get { return _currentPageURL;}
        set
        {
        if (_currentPageURL==value)
        return; // to prevent reload the same page.
            _currentPageURL = value;
            NotifyPropertyChangedCurrentPageURL
        }
    }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementations
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}

// Store in static singleton instance of AppViewModel
public class App : Application
{
    private static Lazy<AppViewModel> _ViewModel=new Lazy<ViewModel>();
    public static AppViewModel ViewModel { get { return _ViewModel.Value; } }
    ....

    public App()
    {
        AppViewModel.PropertyChanged=(s,a) => 
        {
            if (a.PropertyName=="CurrentPageURL")
            {
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(AppViewModel.CurrentPageURL, UriKind.Relative));

            };
        }   
    }
}


// Usage sample
public class Page1ViewModel 
{
    private btnMoveNextPage_Click(object s, EventHandler a) {
        App.ViewModel.CurrentURL="~/Page2.xaml";
    }
}
```